# Is there paginated WSO2 IS soap service call for listing users from secondary user store?

Tags: soap, pagination, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I can successfully list users from WSO2 IS using listUsers of RemoteUserStoreManager soap service call. There is only two options that we can pass. One is filter and other is max limit. However there is no paginated service call for the same. Is there any way possible to achieve the same? For example I want to query users from only 10-20.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.  You can only limit the user and filter them.  Pagination is not supported there.  Usually it is not needed as well. But please let us know your exact requirement.  There may be some others ways to achieve it.

Say; if you want to find a user.  You need to use filter/limit both. As an example,  if user is john.  Filter can be `j*`, then `jo*` and so on till few results are retrieved.